# Square free Numbers

Tags: code-golf, restricted-time

Given a number N, write the shortest complete program to find the number of [square-free integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) below N.

```
Sample Input
100000 
Sample Output
60794
```

Constraints:

1. Should work for all positive N below 1,000,000
2. Should not take more than 10 secs.
3. Please do not use built in functions, please.

Comment: What do you mean with no builtin functions? If I use haskell, I might not even use `+` or `*` - they all are functions.

Comment: @fuzxxl No you can use them, but no functions that directly give you the answer to the question like in Mathematica.

Comment: Basically a copy of the following endless problem on anagol (that one has the limit fixed at 500): http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Square+free+integer.

Comment: @nabb Aha! I did not know about it. Anyways it is not against the spirit of analog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### J, 21 chars

```
+/(]=&#~.)@:q:"0>:i.N
```

Checks for each integer from 1 to N if any prime factor appears more than once.

eg:

```
+/(]=&#~.)@:q:"0>:i.10000
 6083
+/(]=&#~.)@:q:"0>:i.100000
 60794
```

Takes ~3secs for N=1,000,000 (@2GHz,1core)

Comment: I'm not sure if it existed before but as of **J 6.02**, there is the `~:` verb known as `NubSieve` which returns a mask based on the input array where each index is `1` the first time it appears and `0` if it appears again. This allows for a solution using **18 bytes** as `[:+/*/@~:@q:@>:@i.`.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2: 71 chars

```python
i=n=input()
A=[1]*n
while~-i:A[i*i::i*i]=~-n/i/i*[0];i-=1
print~-sum(A)
```

Basically an optimization of [Keith Randall's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/919/20260) of zeroing out numbers that are multiples of squares. The main improvement is directly zeroing out the sublist `A[i*i::i*i]`, which requires awkwardly calculating its length or else Python refuses to do the slice assignment.

Lots of `~-` are used for `-1`. The `~-sum(A)` corrects for `0` being falsely counted as a squarefree number.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 84 characters

```
n=input()
R=range(n)
A=[1]*n
for i in R[2:]:
 for x in R[::i*i]:A[x]=0
print sum(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java Solution**

```
import java.io.*;
    public class Main{
            public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
              int N=Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
              int list[]=new int[N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    list[i]=(i+1);
    }
    for (int i=1;i<N;i++){
    if (Math.sqrt(list[i])-Math.floor(Math.sqrt(list[i]))==0){
    for(int j=i;j<N;j+=(i+1)){
    list[j]=-1;
    }}}
    int c=0;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    if (list[i]!=-1){
    c++;
    }}System.out.println(c);}}
```

IDEONE  http://ideone.com/Yf467

Comment: Hope using sqrt is fine?

Comment: The question says complete program.

Comment: :(   that costed me a lot of characters :(

Comment: It's almost a crime to golf in Java. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 105 bytes

```py
s=input()
C=set()
for q in [k*k for k in range(2,s+1)]:
 i=1
 while q*i<=s:C.add(q*i);i+=1
print s-len(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 11 bytes

```apl
+/≡∘∪⍨⍤⍭¨⍤⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTflfra1frfGoa9GjzoWPOlZpPupd@6h3a@2hFY96N4MYXEB5FOklQBVw2f/a@mCJGUC5R70rELJAevP/tEdtEx719j3qan7Uu@ZR75ZD640ftU181Dc1OMgZSIZ4eAb/T1MwNAABAA)

Bubbler's tacit form. (-4 bytes)

-1 byte from Adám.

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 16 bytes

```apl
{+/{(⊢≡∪)⍭⍵}¨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v1pbv1rjUdeiR50LH3Ws0nzUu/ZR79baQyse9W4GMf6nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moKhAQgAAA)

Same approach as the J answer, `100000` runs under 10 secs on tio, so it should be all good.

### Explanation

```apl
{+/{(⊢≡∪)⍭⍵}¨⍳⍵} 
   {(⊢≡∪)⍭⍵}     square-free checking function
   {     ⍭⍵}     prime factors of ⍵
    (⊢≡∪)        are the unique values equal to the originals?
                 function ends
            ¨⍳⍵  map function to range 1-n
 +/              sum the resulting boolean array
```

Comment: [Tacit 12 bytes.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTflfra1frfGoa9GjzoWPOlZpPupd@6h3a@2hFY96N4MYXEB5FOklQBVw2f84JIH05v9pj9omPOrte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fpmBoAAIA)

Comment: `(⊢≡∪)` → `≡∘∪⍨`

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Count[√Range@#,_^_|1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zm/NK8k@lHHrKDEvPRUB2Wd@Lj4GsNYtf8BRZlAiTQHQwMQiP0PAA)

`SquareFreeQ` is too long anyways.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - <s>119</s> 114

```
I=gets.to_i
m=[]
(s=->i{(I>i*i)?s[i+1]+[i*i]:[]})[2].map{|s|(1..I).map{|x|s*x<I||break;m<<s*x}}
p ([*1...I]-m).size
```

Comment: Try using `((a=*1...I)-m).size` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

### C

**144 Chars**

```
#define m 1000001
x[m];
main(s,o,f){
for(o=2;o*o<m;o++)
for(f=s=o*o;f<m;f+=s)x[f]=1;
scanf("%d",&f);
for(s=0,o=1;o<f;o++)if(!x[o])s++;
printf("%d",s);
}
```

Instantaneous Solution on my crummy PC! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Java - 278 Characters

A golfed version of the [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/897/32114) already demonstrated here without changing the spirit of the answer, because the original poster's idea golfed could have saved 50%, which is huge compared to most other languages!

```
class T {public static void main(String[] a) {int n,i,j;double k;n=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);int l[]=new int[n];for(i=0;i<n;)l[i]=1+i++;for (i=1;i<n;i++) {k=Math.sqrt(l[i]);if(k==Math.floor(k))for (j=i;j<n;j+=i+1)l[j]=-1;}j=0;for(i=0;i<n;)if(l[i++]!=-1)j++;System.out.println(j);}}
```

Specifically, a few Java golfing tricks were used to optimize this:

- Removed long variable names
- Removed the use of a Reader in favor of using an argument (saves a huge amount of characters, including import, Exception handling, and casting the reader in general)
- Removed extra brackets and parentheses using single-line actions for ifs and fors where applicable
- Declare ints beforehand together to reduce calls to int
- Declare a double and optimize square calculation
- Extracted ++ where possible

This shows that the original ungolfed solution of 565 characters can be brought down to a very respectable <300 character answer even with a more structured language like Java.

#### Ungolfed

```
class T {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int n, i, j;
        double k;
        n = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
        int l[] = new int[n];
        for (i = 0; i < n;)
            l[i] = 1 + i++;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            k = Math.sqrt(l[i]);
            if (k == Math.floor(k))
                for (j = i; j < n; j += i + 1)
                    l[j] = -1;
        }
        j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n;)
            if (l[i++] != -1)
                j++;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can be 272 with some stray whitespace removed. I think you can use `(int)k` instead of `Math.floor(k)`, bringing the total down to 265.

Comment: @DLosc I got a can't cast String to int when I did that. Would have if I could :(

Comment: Huh... even though `k` is a `double`? I don't really know Java, but that just seems odd to me.

Comment: @DLosc I'll check again tomorrow. Maybe I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

## GNU coreutils, 44 bytes

```sh
seq $1|factor|sed '$d;/\( .*\)\1\b/d'|wc -l
```

This factors every number up to N, removes the last line (as we're only counting results strictly less than N), and removes any line with a repeated word.  Finally, we count the remaining lines.

The regular expression `\( .*\)\1\b` looks over-generous, but it takes advantage of what we know about the output of `factor` - the factors will be in ascending order, with exactly one space between each.

With N=1,000,000, this completes on my machine in about ¼ second.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ_=k)eZâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9V89ayllWuI&input=MTAwMDAw)

```
õ_=k)eZâ     :Implicit input of integer U
õ            :Range [1,U]
 _           :Map each Z
  =          :  Reassign to Z
   k         :  Prime factors of Z
    )        :  End reassignment
     e       :  Test equality with
      Zâ     :  Z deduplicated
             :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```